# In espresso How to getthe first ImageView?

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my view, there are two ImageViews. All of the properties are same. It does not have id, content-description, etc.
I want to click the first one, but I could not find the method to do it.

My Code:

> Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withClassName(Matchers.endsWith(ImageView.class.getSimpleName())))

Answer (score 0):

You need to call both `perform` and `click` once you have the proper view that you want. From your question it's not clear whether you are getting that view from your calls to matcher or not. If you're not getting the right view, the easiest way is to set an `id` property on the two ImageViews so that you can uniquely identify them.
Once you've done that, you'll make a call something like this:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.imageView1)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

This will perform a click event on the ImageView that you've matched.